# Monorepo microservices architecture - Lerna powered by Nx

Tags: github, microservices, github-actions, lerna, nrwl-nx

#### Background

We have a Lerna/NX monorepo with multiple packages/subrepos within it, and each one currently has it’s own associated workflows for GitHub.

We are now trying to build out some APIs using a microservice architecture within that monorepo, and have a few snagging queries regarding this.

**Question 1 - shared dependencies**

We will have a minimum of 5 microservices for our MVP (more planned in the future) all consumed via an API Gateway. These microservices are going to be sharing a lot of dependencies, with a few unique dependencies for specific microservices depending on its purpose, such as 3rd party SDKs/prisma client/etc.

*Is there a way we can utilise a “shared” package.json for the shared dependencies, whilst also populating it on build with the unique dependencies which would be housed within the package.json within each microservice?*

See below image for an example of the folder structure with a “root” package.json that houses the shared dependencies, and within each microservice “sub-package” we would house the microservice specific dependencies.

[OSC-API microservices structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYQmv.png)

The purpose of this is to avoid the tedious task of going through each package individually to update the shared dependencies. Instead we would just have to update the “shared” package.json.

If this is something that just screams bad practice or “SHOULDN'T be done” feel free to say so.

**Question 2 - GitHub workflows**

*Is there a way we can easily create a singular workflow that would cater for all microservices in 1 .yml file?*

This would need to individually build the affected packages based on commits in the PR triggering the workflow. I.e. if Microservice 1, has commits, but nothing else then only microservice 1 gets built and deployed. However, the caveat is if there IS a “shared” package.json then any changes to this should cause all microservices to be rebuilt with the new dependencies.

It is also worth noting here, we do not have a large degree of DevOps experience, so what we currently have is a lot of trial and error, and as such would like to keep it somewhat simplified. However, if there is ample explanation to more complex suggestions would not mind trying them out.

The reason we want a single file is because we already have 3/4 workflows for each package in our monorepo, and as soon as we start building out these microservices, the workflows folder is going to start getting very bulky very quickly if we have to target each microservice with an individual workflow.yml

We have considered using the “working-directory” flag (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-set-the-default-shell-and-working-directory), but it does not seem to work with marketplace actions that do not allow you to specify subfolders

We have also considered moving the individual packages to the root of the monorepo, this results in multiple workflows, it seems to work alright, are there any negatives associated with doing it in this manner

eg.

```
- run: rm -v -r ./package.json ./node_modules
- run: mv -v -f packages/osc-package1/* .
```